# adding one point from the Stone-Cech compactification

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, stone-cech-compactification

Let $X$ be any non-compact Tychonoff space and $\beta X$ be its Stone-Čech compactification.
The following fact is known: any point $p$ from the reminder $\beta X \setminus X$ is not a $G_{\delta}$-set in $\beta X$. Consider a topological space $X^{\ast}$ which is the space $X \cup \{p\}$
equipped with the topology induced from $\beta X$. It is easy to see that if $X$ is a $\sigma$-compact space, i.e. $X$ is a countable union of compact subspaces, then $p$ is $G_{\delta}$ in $X^{\ast}$.
I ask the following question: is the converse true?

In other words a general question is: does there exist a non- $\sigma$-compact Tychonoff
space $X$ such that $\{p\}$ is a $G_{\delta}$-set in $X \cup \{p\}$ for any point $p$
from the reminder $\beta X \setminus X$?

Comment: One characterization of realcompactness is that $X$ is realcompact if and only if for each $p \in \beta X \setminus X$, there is a zero-set $Z$ of $\beta X$ such that $p \in Z \subseteq \beta X \setminus X$.  Therefore, taking $X$ to be any realcompact space which is not $\sigma$-compact gives an example.

Comment: You are right, thank you.

Comment: So $\Bbb P$, the irrationals, will do. It's Lindelöf so realcompact. And from its homeomorphic representation $\omega^\omega$ it's easily seen to be non-$\sigma$-compact.